# Authentication failed - Cannot clone remote repository by Git (Only occurred in Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, git, windows-authentication, egit

I am on Eclipse 2018.12 (actually same issue occurs from other version like Mars2 or Scala-IDE 4.7), I am struggling to get Git/EGit pass authentication while cloning remote repository, which is deployed on my company's server.

The same issue never occur while I am using Git command like or Git GUI or IntelliJ, but only by Eclipse (regardless of Eclipse version or any type of Git plugin)

I think the difference here is from Git bash or Git GUI or IntelliJ, the authentication is implicitly by verifying my Windows credential from local OS credential store with remote server. So Git bash/GUI and IntelliJ never pop up the login screen.

However, the default setup page from Eclipse asks for username/password every time. And after I enter the correct information, the same pop up message just show up again and again, like a sign that the authentication never pass.

Please see screenshot below.

[image: Setup remote repository]

[image: Same login screen pops up again and again]

Is there anyway to let Eclipse to follow the same way of authentication like Git

Comment: Just check the checkbox _Store in Secure Store_. Eclipse uses JGit, a Git implementation in Java, whereas most other IDEs and editors delegate to the command line Git which has to be installed.

Comment: @howlger thanks for the information. I checked the box but the login window pop up again. Is there a way to let Eclipse delegate to command line Git? I don't see anywhere to select Git installation like for Mave setup

Comment: Which protocol do you use? Delegating to the command line is not an option for good reasons. What exactly must be done to reproduce this issue (for me it works without problems).

Comment: @howlger tried `http` and `https`, both gives the same error, the git repository is on TFS server, kind of specific environment that is difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Maybe this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ab23a01b-4397-4dbb-821f-6e68d458ad9f/eclipse-and-egit-cant-push-to-tfs-server?forum=tee

Comment: @howlger hmm thank you. Looks like it may caused by a server side setting instead of local setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue here.  Seems that eGit doesn't support Windows Authentication where as command line Git does.

Work around is to use a Personal Access Token as the password and anything as the username.

You can create a PAT by logging into your TFS/Azure DevOps Website, click on your profile icon at the top right, select Security.  Then create a new Personal Access Token and copy the token into the password box in eclipse.  Maximum life of a token is 1 year, so you'll need to make a new one every year.

Comment: Hope I can like this answer a thousand times. Well I should blame myself didn't spend time to play around on the TFS site. But your answer did save me hours of research time. Much appreciated !